# How would one undo loading a quicksave in Kerbal Space Program?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I just reverted to a quicksave in KSP, but I had forgotten that I had not actually made a quicksave during this mission (or in the last few missions), and thus hours of work were deleted.

Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: I wish there was.  I've done the same thing, but I think the quickload feature replaces your persistence file at the same time it loads it, so there's no way to retrieve it, if you haven't backed it up manually.

Comment: This is the age-old curse of the quickload, a scourge on gamers since the first quicksave was invented.

Comment: I have a feeling that you're out of luck.  Could be worse, at least you didn't end flight on a space station...

Comment: @MBraedley The End Flight has been removed now.  You can revert the launch, if you haven't gone back to the Space Center yet, but otherwise, you have to manually terminate it from your radar room.

Comment: @fbueckert: I know, but that still doesn't mean I'm not bitter from the old way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is an old post but it IS possible to "undo" a quickload because I've done it before more than once with 0.20 and 0.22.

The key is to react as soon as you realize what you've done.  In Windows, just hit Alt-Ctrl-Del and bring up the task manager, select ksp.exe from the processes tab and click on "End Task", this will kill the game.  Restart the game and load your mission, then you will be at the point where your game last autosaved, *before* you did the quickload.

This works only if you do it quick enough, because a short time after the quickload mistake, the game WILL autosave again which will overwrite the persistent file, but it doesn't do it right away, and a quickload does NOT overwrite the persistent save file.

Again, I have done this more than once because I've made the same mistake, and I can tell you that it works.

Comment: Indeed, `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` saved many Kerbal lifes for me too.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who does this now, I found a 'Backups' folder under the saves directory, which appears to have copies of persistent.sfs made at the last autosave - they could be useful - and saved me a few hours. YMMV.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

As with saves in most games featuring a save system, **no extra data is saved while loading**. This means that, whenever you load (be it quick load or otherwise), your game reverts to the state it was during the save you're loading. Once you've gone back, there's no way to load into the "future" again unless you have a later save (which includes autosaves - they linger if you force-close the game soon enough after quickloading) in store.

So, in summary, there is **no way to load forward** to where you in this case were. The progress between your latest save (which, as mentioned, includes autosaves) and the point you loaded from is irreparably lost.

Comment: This is incorrect...  It may be possible with many games actually (see my answer), but it is definitely possible with KSP.

Answer (score 0):

You can rightclick the savefile under programms(xY) -steam -steamapps -common -ksp -saves and go to something like "redo previos versions" or similar. Then copy the file from the date you know your stuff was fine, delete the file in the saves fil and paste the copied version in there. This of course will only be useful if the version you want was the last thing you did before closing KSP, and also delete the progress after that date.

-READ THE WHOLE THING BEFORE STARTING TO WORK-

Answer (score -1):

If you use a Mac, and use time machine, restore your save file!

Comment: This is not directly relevant to the question, and it is not true as you would only be able to restore an old version, as Time Machine does not backup instantly.