# A way to practice certain stages?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm wondering if there is a way of practicing different stages of a flight. I am currently trying to land on the Mun and after some hours i just made my first semi successful attempt at it. But most of the time goes into taking off properly and setting up maneuvers to get close to the Mun. Is there a way to skip all that and just do a couple of landing practices?

I can imagine doing some more complicated things further away takes a lot of time and a single mistake can be fatal so it is very hard to even practice the later steps in the progress. Currently i am doing the career mode so a solution that fits career mode is welcome but not necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do to reduce the cost of screwing up.  The first thing to do is to quicksave often (defaults to <kbd>F5</kbd>, load the last quicksave by holding <kbd>F9</kbd>).  This means that you can get your ship into Kerbal orbit (quicksave), do your transfer burn (quicksave), do your Munar injection burn (quicksave), and then your deorbit burn (quicksave) without worrying about having to redo the entire mission.  If you want to practice landing, then just try to land, and then load the last quicksave, which should be just after your deorbit burn.

Note that there is only a single quicksave available per save, and if you load it, and it's too old, you're basically stuck with it, [unless you catch it quickly enough.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126648/how-would-one-undo-loading-a-quicksave-in-kerbal-space-program)

The second option is to create tutorial/scenario saves.  These use the same savefile format as the rest of the game, but also include end goals.  I'm not familiar with steps required to create them, but I've tried some community generated ones in the past.  Take a look through [Kerbal Spaceport](http://kerbalspaceport.com/), the [forums](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/), and the [KSP subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/kerbalspaceprogram) for any that you think will fit the bill.

Your final option is [save editing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151535/).  Skip the drudgery of launch and just place your lander directly into Munar orbit!  [Scott Manley](https://www.youtube.com/user/szyzyg) has done [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wXVm3M2I2w) all about editing your save to do fun and interesting stuff, or to save some time.

There may be some other options available to you as well,  but with these three methods, you should be able to do plenty of practice while also completing missions.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't even know you could save. That will be sufficient for now. Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> now lets you name your quick-saves, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> lets you reload a quicksave by name.