# Move kerbals in KSP - to save Jebediah from an unjust fate

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm hoping for some help. I'm fairly new to the game so please bare with me. I recently reloaded a quicksave instead of creating one by accident. According to [How would one undo loading a quicksave in Kerbal Space Program?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126648/how-would-one-undo-loading-a-quicksave-in-kerbal-space-program) it's likely I've now lost the old state (didn't leave in time)

But to add insult to injury I quicksaved at a time when I had gotten a big lander back to Kerbin and wanted Jebediah to take a soil sample. I wasn't sure if he would survive the fall so I saved it prior to letting go of the ladder. However in the reload Jeb appears about a meter to the left of the lander and promptly falls to the ground and dies. I can accept my lost  progress after this save but given all his science (and life) I'd really like to bring him home. I tried tweaking the quick save but every reload had the same effect.

Any help or advice on where to aim would be hugely appreciated...

Thanks!
Possibly relevent section:

```
VESSEL
        {
            pid = 1dab3465e53d4bc89125c16c2e51e410
            name = Jebediah Kerman
            type = EVA
            sit = FLYING
            landed = False
            landedAt = 
            splashed = False
            met = 7.90000000735745
            lct = 2154667.37390431
            root = 0
            lat = 15.431993254746
            lon = -330.337250733857
            alt = 686.741724181804 <--- Tried editing this, nothing changed
            hgt = 1.991011
            nrm = -0.009900075,0.9233786,-0.3837628
            rot = -0.6215439,-0.1967535,0.3950912,-0.6472049
            CoM = 0,0,0
            stg = 0
            prst = False
            ref = 0
            cPch = 0.544
            cHdg = 2.27
            cMod = 0
            ORBIT
            {
                SMA = 301069.766658943
                ECC = 0.995174584633339
                INC = 15.4319930748073
                LPE = 270.000318325192
                LAN = -59.082056632706
                MNA = 3.14139282715152
                EPH = 2154675.29390432
                REF = 1
            }
```

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151535/editing-kerbal-space-program-save-files-for-kso
here's another save. maybe just experiment with those values a bit (getting it into orbit etc..)

Comment: How adverse would you be to using cheats? There is a command that disables gravity, this would allow you to lower Jeb to the ground using his EVA pack, then you can re-enable gravity and continue normally.

Comment: Lesson: KSP savegames are somewhat wonky, especially with exact Kerbal positions.

Comment: Agreed Frank. And if I had intended to have any interaction with them at this point I wouldn't have been so surprised... I guess I'll just try to remember to delete my quicksave after closing the game every time to be on the safe side.

Comment: CyanAngel, I'd rather not use cheats but as far as I'm concerned a cheat to fix what the game broke isn't really an issue. I'll investigate doing what you say. If you have any useful wikis or resources for it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Ewanw Info about what I meantioned can be found [here](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Debug_Toolbar)

Comment: @CyanAngel thanks! Did you want to put that as an answer for me to approve? (I'm a bit of an asking newbie)

Comment: @Ewanw added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KSP includes a "Debug Menu", which you can access with `Alt + F12`. From within this menu there is an option to disable gravity. Once gravity is off, go to the Kerbal you need to save and use the EVA pack to gently lower them to the ground.

You can read more about the Debug Menu [here](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Debug_Toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

Another option that worked for me was to modify the Kerbal's state to set `sit = LANDED` and `landed = True`. The Kerbal was then fine when I loaded the quick save.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've turned off `MissingCrewRespawn` for your save, your dead Kerbals will reappear after a little while. If the only thing you're trying to do is keep Jebediah, you're already safe there.

If on the other hand you want that soil sample, CyanAngel's suggestion to turn off gravity and get to a safer position with EVA thrusters would be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping to save the Kerbal. He was also, unfortunately, holding other experiments at the time so I was quite eager to save him...